# Error managing external logins after migrating from membership

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, migration, asp.net-identity

- I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and WebForms (C#) for my website.
- I migrated from AspNet Membership to Identity 2.
- I can log in/log out locally.
- I can login using an  external login (Facebook) (If I have already an
  external login with Facebook to an user).
- I can remove the external login in ManageLogins.aspx
- I can add a new user using an external login (Facebook) in
  RegisterExternalLogin.aspx.

But if I want to add an external login in ManageLogins.aspx on an existing user, I receive this error after a while:
**Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerTimeoutException: The server request timed out.**

Does anyone has an idea?
Thanks
rubenc

Here is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="CMS.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings configSource="db.config" />
  <appSettings configSource="app.config" />
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" batch="false">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />-->
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <siteMap defaultProvider="MenuSiteMap1" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="MenuSiteMap1" description="Menu SiteMap provider" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="MenuPrincipal.sitemap" securityTrimmingEnabled="true" />
        <add name="MenuSiteMap1_en" description="Menu SiteMap provider" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="MenuPrincipalEn.sitemap" securityTrimmingEnabled="true" />
        <add name="AspNetXmlSiteMapProvider_pie" description="SiteMap provider which reads in pie.sitemap XML files." type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" securityTrimmingEnabled="true" siteMapFile="Menu_pie.sitemap" />
        <add name="AspNetXmlSiteMapProvider_pie_en" description="SiteMap provider which reads in pie_en.sitemap XML files." type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" securityTrimmingEnabled="true" siteMapFile="Menu_pie_en.sitemap" />
        <add name="SiteMap_CongReportes" description="SiteMap provider which reads in pie.sitemap XML files." type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~\01_Congregacion\CongReportes.sitemap" />
        <add name="SiteMap_CongReportes_en" description="SiteMap provider which reads in pie.sitemap XML files." type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~\01_Congregacion\CongReportesEn.sitemap" />
        <add name="SiteMap_GruposReportes" description="SiteMap provider which reads in pie.sitemap XML files." type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~\02_Grupos\GruposReportes.sitemap" />
        <add name="SiteMap_GruposReportes_en" description="SiteMap provider which reads in pie.sitemap XML files." type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~\02_Grupos\GruposReportesEn.sitemap" />
      </providers>
    </siteMap>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity" />
      </namespaces>
    <controls>
      <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
    </controls></pages>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="jw_cmsConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
      <add name="Reserved-ReportViewerWebControl-axd" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EnvDTE" publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845DCD8080CC91" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

- When I upgraded to Identity the first time I received this error:
  Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error
  occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code
  returned from the server was: 0.
- Then I upgraded AjaxToolKit to latest version I received this error:
  Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerTimeoutException: The server request
  timed out.
- After upgrading Microsoft.AspNet.ScriptManager.MSAjax to latest
  version, now I receive this error: Unable to get property
  'PRM_ServerError' of undefined or null reference.

Answer (score 0):

This error rise when an asynchronous postback exceed the time limit. means that you have a long running process on the server and the response doesn't comeback from the server. To solve this try setting `ScriptManager.AsyncPostBackTimeout` greater than default value.
I found these links helpfull.
[ASP Forums](http://forums.asp.net/t/1042916.aspx?Sys%20WebForms%20PageRequestManagerTimeoutException)

[Microsoft MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb310955%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the replied, although I don't think is a timeout problem, I tried your suggestion and didn't work. I think is another problem because if I use a recent created asp.net web application Web forms (individual user account) and connect with the same identity database, everything works fine. And I'm using the same code and account/*.aspx pages in my website. (Copied from the newly created web app).

Comment: how much is the waiting time is it above 90 seconds or greater?

Comment: I think is related with the scriptmanager because first I was getting server error code: 0 and after I updated to Ajax toolkit version 15.1, I started receiving the timeout error.

Comment: right now I have it with AsyncPostBackTimeOut="36000" and it is still waiting for a response for more than 10 minutes now.

Comment: Can you downgrade back to what your Ajax toolkit version was? and see if the problem still exists. if exist then it is obviously belongs to the timing.

Comment: I have a copy before the upgrading, I restored it and now I receive this error: Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104069/discussion-between-ruben-and-naser-dostdar).